# Doing the crossjoin with aggregate function in mdx

Tags: mdx

I have three dimensions in my Cube - Month , Products and Services.My requirement is to find the sum of top five products based on months dimension and then I have to find the different services for the sum of top 5.I am able to find the sum of top 5 but when i try to do crossjoin with Service , the result which i get doesnt give correct data.
Please help

Comment: What have you tried so far? can you provide a query on which we can work on to hel you?